# Is it "legal" or "clean code" to have a nested class in a viewmodel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My situation:
I have a viewmodel, and inside that viewmodel i have a dictionary storing a string and an instance of that nested class. The nested class contains 3 simple variables that are only used in that viewmodel and nowhere else through the entire application. The reason i'm using a nested class for this is because the values have to remain mutable. (So Tuple and Struct were no options).

My question is:
Is this the right approach? Is this considered "clean code"? Is it "legal" to have an inner class in a viewmodel?

Here is an example of my code:

Nested class:

```
        public class BoolCodePair {
        public bool Scanned { get; set; }
        public string EquipmentCode { get; set; }
        public BoolCodePair(bool scanned, string equipmentcode) {
            Scanned = scanned;
            EquipmentCode = equipmentcode;
        }
    }
```

Class it is nested in contains:

```
        public Dictionary<string, BoolCodePair> EquipmentScanned = new Dictionary<string, BoolCodePair>() {
        { "test", new BoolCodePair(false, "") },
        { "test", new BoolCodePair(false, "") },
        { "test" , new BoolCodePair(false, "") },
        { "test", new BoolCodePair(false, "")},
        { "test", new BoolCodePair(false, "") },
        { "test" , new BoolCodePair(false, "")},
        { "test" , new BoolCodePair(false, "")},
        { "test" , new BoolCodePair(false, "")}
    };
```

Comment: It is an interesting question, yet I'm afraid you won't get a lot of attention without showing parts of your code for better understanding. Can you add a simplified version of your code to your question?

Comment: Edited in some code :)

Comment: It's completely clean. Of course, some people will nitpick and tell you "one class = one file", but that's just an opinion. If this class is never and will never be used out of this one, it might as well stay here. That being said, this question is more suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as it is not a problem in need of resolution per se.

Comment: The more arguable part may be the _have to remain mutable_.

Comment: Could you elaborate? @HenkHolterman

Comment: Completely agree with @Kilazur. In my opinion you can use nested class in this case. I've simillar solutions with nested class in ViewModels when I'm absolutely sure that this nested class will never be used in other place.